# Jest testing can't do snapshot and other test cases due to destructure property in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing some jest snapshot tests for my react component.
When run test, error in console:
**TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'period' of 'plan' as it is undefined.**

test.spec.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Payment from '../index';

const setUp = (props) => shallow(<Payment {...props} />);

describe('must render <Payment /> component', () => {
    let component;

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = setUp({});
    });

    it('must be defined <Payment />', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('must match snapshot <Payment />', () => {
        const wrapper = renderer.create(component).toJSON();

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

components.tsx

```
const Payment: React.FC<PaymentTypes> = ({ period, plan }: PaymentTypes) => {
    const { period: terms } = plan;

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                <p>
                    {`If you don’t cancel, you will be
                    charged ${terms[period].price}/${terms[period].abbreviation}.`}

                </p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Payment;
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey4gh.png)

Comment: You don't provide *any* props, so period and plan will both be undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks. Props in tests.

Resolved.